# sorting a column manully through user interface

Tags: hibernate, sorting

I am using hibernate to retrieving data from database. My UI shows different columns in table. I want to implement sorting functionality on the columns. [image: this icon should be shown on column]

On triggering the icon the name should be sorted like A-Z then Z-A.

please help me in this.

Comment: do you want to sort the in-memory data or you want to hit the DB?

Comment: @DebojitSaikia , The elements are retrieved from database only.

Comment: but you want to sort the data which you have already loaded from DB.. right?

Comment: yes right, data is already loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort your data by using a `Comparator` (assuming you don't want to hit the DB). Suppose you have a list of `Category` instances (`categoryList`) which is being displayed on your UI:

```
class Category{
private Long id;
private String categoryName;
private String otherProperty;
}
```

Now you can define custom strategies using `Comparator` interface to sort the `Category` instances present in your `Category list`:

```
class StartegyOne implements Comparator<Category> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Category c1, Categoryc2) {
        return c1.getCategoryName().compareTo(c2.getCategoryName());
    }

}
```

This `StrategyOne` will order Categories based on lexicographic ordering of their `categoryNames`; which can be achieved with `Collections.sort`:

```
Collections.sort(categoryList, AN_INSTANCE_OF_StrategyOne);
```

You can consider storing an instance of this `Strategy` class in a private static final field and reusing it:

```
/*This is the class that receives the sort action*/
class SortActionHandler{

private static final Comparator<Category> CATEGORY_ORDER = 
                                        new Comparator<Category>() {
            public int compare(Category c1, Categoryc2) {
                return c1.getCategoryName().compareTo(c2.getCategoryName());
            }
    };

//call this method to sort your list according to category names
private void sortList(List<Category> categoryList){
Collections.sort(categoryList, CATEGORY_ORDER);
}
}
```

Comment: I dont want to use any more interface, need solution with existing files. I have model `Category` then its `DAOImpl` file, changes in DAOImpl and Category model are welcomed

Comment: on clicking the sort button on UI, you are submitting the code to some class.. right? any changes in that class is okay?

Comment: @Debojit..  yeah, it would be okay.